# Skip or Ignore non-existing key with to_entries in jq

Tags: json, key, jq

I'm trying to create a massive CSV file converted from each `*.json` file. This snippet works until it faces the file that doesn't have the key (`hobby`).

**Original**

```
{
  "name": "bob",
  "hobby": [
    "baseball",
    "baseketball"
   ]
}
```

**jq snippet**

```
cat *.json | jq '.name as $n | .hobby | to_entries[] | [ $n, .value]'
```

**It works**

`[][]...` is a pre-format when creating CSV with jq

```
[
  "bob",
  "baseball"
]
[
  "bob",
  "baseketball"
]
```

https://jqplay.org/s/L-SmqiN-jw

**However** if the `.hobby` key doesn't exist it fails miserably.

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:6): null (null) has no keys
exit status 5
```

https://jqplay.org/s/gapUv1Tpmb

I tried to use if block but it seems not correct. How can we do such a thing either

- return `[]` (empty array)
- skip jq excution for the current working file with this problem and go to the next

Comment: `.hobby // []`  or use `if` or use `select`

Answer (score 1):

One of many possibilities would be to use `try`:

```
.name as $n | .hobby | try to_entries[] | [ $n, .value]
```

`try EXP` is equivalent to `try EXP catch empty`.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following:

```
{
  "name": "bob",
  "hobby": [
    "baseball",
    "baseketball"
  ]
}

$ cat file | jq -c "{name,hobby:.hobby[]}|[.[]]"

["bob","baseball"]
["bob","baseketball"]
```